# MySQL: update column if it exists else do nothing?

Tags: mysql

How to do the following:

```
if table has column 'name' - update 'name', else - do nothing?
```

My working sql in a transaction is

```
UPDATE tmp set name = NULL
```

tmp table kees the record to update and turning name into NULL is required for duplicate procedure. However, some tables do not have 'name' field.

So, is it possible to update column to null if exists, otherwise, just do nothing?

Comment: I don't understands downwotes, but, anyway, for those, who came up with the same problem - reading from (or writing to) a column that does not exist without error (e.g. silent ignore) is not possible with mysql. Column name (column's existence in a table) is to be known. Workaround - read first information schema to get all column names and proceed accordingly.  The process will require transaction to proceed with several sqls.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it is not possible. Moreover I would recommend never make any modifications on a number of tables at once. In general each table is unique and setting fields to NULL basing on just a field name could lead to loss of important data.